# Highslide adding font-size : 0px...Is this a No no?

Tags: seo, highslide

I am hoping to hear from the people at highslide. I noticed that our rankings had dropped on our site and although I do not think this maybe the cause I would like to know if this may be something to worry about.

I noticed highslide is adding a lot of font-size: 0px and hidden text, etc.This seems to be a big no no on what I am reading on google. This may come across as 'hidden text' and I was alittle worried that this is affecting our site.
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353

Any insights on this would be very helpful.
Dan

Comment: Where are you seeing font-size: 0px or hidden text? That doesn't occur in any of the Highslide JS standard CSS.

Comment: Take a look here...
http://www.highslide.com/examples/inline.html

Comment: It looks like the highslide adds inline.

Comment: I'm still not seeing anything there that would upset a search bot. Look at the HTML coding on the page, not at what the Javascript might be generating on the fly. The search bots don't execute any Javascript, so they see only what's on the page and in the CSS file.

Comment: I see what you are saying, however unless I am looking at it the wrong way, the html is showing the <td> styling. So you are saying that is being hidden by the javascript? http://www.highslide.com/examples/inline.html

Comment: Just view the page source - CTRL-U in Firefox or Chrome, right-click/View Source in IE. It's only 50 lines of HTML (many of them blank or comments), and there are no tables on that page.

Comment: Now I see what you are saying. So the crtl-u is a way of looking at what is going on without the javascript showing? I do not see all that inline stuff when I do that. Nice. I was worried about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the poster has misunderstood something about search bots. They don't actually execute whatever Javascript is on the page, so they don't see any of the "behind the curtain" tricks the Javascript is employing to make the magic happen. The HTML and CSS code don't contain any of these "dangerous" or "forbidden" elements, and therefore don't raise any red flags with the search bots.

Having said that, however, any display mechanism that uses Javascript to display content is going to be at least somewhat less SEO-friendly than simple HTML. If you're using Javascript to display the mydog.jpg image and its comment, that's going to be a bit tougher for a search bot to understand than it would be to have a thumbnail that actually links to a separate page called mydog.html that contains just mydog.jpg and its caption.

Within the last year or so, however, the Google bot, in particular, has become much more adept at understanding the layout of a Highslide JS gallery. Images on my pages that never used to appear in search results are now routinely popping up. The code hasn't changed - the bot has.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad thing to me. There are legitimate reasons for hiding text that are SE-friendly but they almost always involve using `display:none;`. Even if there is a legit reason for highslide to do this I doubt the search engines consider this and this is probably raising a red flag.

Comment: That is what I am worried about, even in their sample coding you have...
position: absolute; top: -9999px
visibility: hidden;
font-size: 0px;
alot of repeats with transparent;
I'm wondering if this could be the cause of our rankings dropping.